# Factorization of polynomial over R

Tags: polynomials

[image: **enter image description here**]

Here is my question related to the factorization of polynomials over R. I have 2 questions regarding my highlighting text.

1)The first highlight: I don't understand why if we can prove $q(x)$ has real coefficients, then it will have as much $(x-\overline{\lambda})$ as $(x-\lambda)$.

2)The second highlight: Why $x$ can be in $R$ only ? What if $x\in C$ ?

Comment: The second highlight means $q(x)$ is real if $x$ is real. It does not mean $x$ can be in $\mathbb R$ only.

Comment: According to what you mention, as from my understanding, he is stating the statement 
"If $x\in R,$ then $q(x)$ has real coefficients." What if the case if $x\in C?$, Will $q(x)$ has real coefficients? Does this affect the proof that q(x) has real coefficients?

Comment: Is the coefficient of a polynomial dependent on its variable?

Comment: yes. every polynomial has unique coefficients.

Comment: I mean $q(x)=1+x$ has real coefficients even if $x$ can be complex. That is, the coefficients of a polynomial do not depend on the variable.

Comment: Let me clarify one thing with you in order to make sure I fully understand it. 
Does that mean the author just selects $x\in R$ and hence he get $q(x)$ has real coefficients of the form $q(x)=a_0+\cdots+a_{m-2}x^{m-2}$ where $a_j\in R$. Then from here, even if we have $x\in C$, this polynomial is still valid right? ( as this polynomial is unique, it can't have different coefficients with different $x$ )

Comment: Yes, that is what I think the author is saying.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are as many $(x-\overline{\lambda})$ as $(x-\lambda)$ because $(x-\overline{\lambda})(x-\lambda)$ will have only real coefficients.
Let $\lambda:=a+bi$, then $\overline{\lambda}=a-bi$, so:
$$(x-\overline{\lambda})(x-\lambda)=x^2-\lambda x-\overline{\lambda}x+\overline{\lambda}\lambda=x^2-x(\lambda+\overline{\lambda})+\overline{\lambda}\lambda$$
Now, $\lambda+\overline{\lambda}=2a \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\overline{\lambda}\lambda=a^2+b^2 \in \mathbb{R}$
So if there is no $(x-\overline{\lambda})$ for a $(x-\lambda)$, then the polynom will look like this: $Q(x)=(x-\lambda)P(x)$, where $P(x)$ has only real coefficients. $Q(x)=(x-\lambda)P(x)=(x-a-bi)P(x)=xP(x)-aP(x)-ibP(x)$. Now, $xP(x)$ and $aP(x)$ has real coefficients only, but the $-ibP(x)$ has only imaginary, so $Q(x)$'s coefficients are not real.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. What I asked is, why $q(x)$ has real coefficients implies that there are as many $(x-\overline{\lambda})$ as $(x-\lambda)$?

Comment: @LingMinHao Did you read the whole answer?

Comment: @LingMinHao Multiplying a polynom with real coefficients by $(x-\lambda)=(x-a-bi)$ will result a polynom with complex coefficients. The only way you can make it real again is to multiply it by $(x-\overline{\lambda})$, because that will make the $(x-\lambda)(x-\overline{\lambda})$ real.

Comment: @LingMinHao Why can only $(x-\overline{\lambda})$ make $(x-\lambda)$ real? Because $(x-z_1)(x-z_2)=x^2-x(z_1+z_2)+z_1z_2$ and we want both $z_1+z_2$ and $z_1z_2$ to be real. From the first: $a_1+b_1i+a_2+b_2i=(a_1+a_2)+i(b_1+b_2)$. The only way for it to be real is the $b_1+b_2=0$. For the second condition: $a_1a_2+a_1b_2i+a_2b_1i-b_1b_2$, we can see that $a_1b_2+a_2b_1$ must be zero. but $b_1=-b_2$, so $-a_1b_1+a_2b_1$ must be zero, so $a_1=a_2$. So it's only possible with $z_1=a_1+b_1i$ and $z_2=a_1-b_1i=\overline{z_1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is clearer for me now.