# What does "induction on the degree of p" mean here

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

For the following proof:
[image]

Extra details:
4.7 states that a polynomial is uniquely determined by its coefficients
4.14 is the fundamental theorem of algebra
4.15 states if a polynomial with real coefficients has a complex root, then the conjugate is also a root of the polynomial.

Another question involving this proof is [Factorization of polynomial over R](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2623207/factorization-of-polynomial-over-r)
but my question is a little different.

My understanding of the proof (Please correct me if I'm wrong): for any $p \in P(R)$, we can also treat it as a member of $P(C)$ since the real numbers are also complex. If $p$ only has real roots, then it will obviously be in the form that we are trying to prove by the fundamental theorem of algebra. If $p$ were to a complex but not real root, then since $p$ has real coefficients, the conjugate will also be a root. Thus we can express $p(x)=(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)q(x)$. If we then show $q(x)$ only has real coefficients, then we can apply this whole thing again where we treat $q$ as a member of $P(C)$ and then repeat until it is reduced down into the form that is given.

My question: What does "Then by using induction on the degree of $p$ we can conclude $(x-\lambda)$ appears as many times as $(x-\overline {\lambda})$ mean. The main point of my confusion is the "using induction". I'm relatively new to proofs but when I hear of induction, I think of proving for the base case, assuming its true for case $k$, then proving it for $k+1$, but I'm not sure how that works here.

Comment: The base case is showing it true for all polynomials of degree $0$ (i.e.  all the constant functions $p(x) =c$).  Then the induction step is to prove that if it is true for all polynomials of degree $n$, then it will be true for polynomials of degree $n+1$.

Comment: Okay.   If $p$ has degree $n$ the we can split out $(x-\lambda)$ and $(x-\overline \lambda)$ to get $p(x) = (x-\lambda)(x-\overline \lambda)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ has degree of $n-2$.  We can do the same thing for $q(x)$ to get $p(x)=(x-\lambda)(x-\overline \lambda)(x-\lambda_2)(x-\overline \lambda_2)r(x)$ where $r(x)$ has degree $n-4$ and so on....  Whenever you say "and so on" you are doing induction.

Comment: @fleablood but doesn't the proof revolve around p being non constant? would the base case be for degree 1?

Comment: Actually the base case is degree $p$ is some value $K$ and your indcution step is going *down* to show that if it is true for degree $n$ then it is true for degree $n-2$.

Comment: Ohh, so i do the opposite (go down by 2) in this case rather than showing it is true for n+1? I didn't know that was possible thank you!